# Under construction page when I enable https

Tags: 7

I enabled https:// in a Drupal 7 site, but I get the *Under construction* page every time I try to access it. When I try to log in, I get a 404 error.

Can anybody tell me what I am missing?

I’ve used the default .htaccess and settings configuration.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your hosting configuration.

Comment: As I get through the documentation I run the steps as follows and everything seems to be working since now any request is over “https://“ I got access to the .htaccess file on the hosting side and have modified it as the documentation suggest. I feel like something in drupal 7 instance is giving me an issue since before we did all of this changes to run everything over “https://“ I got this error only when you type “https://“ in the address, but before everything was working ok